# Regex Keyword search near date

Tags: regex, azure-information-protection

I added comments to similar posts but guess that may not be the best way to get an answer?

I need to input some regular expressions into a search (Azure Information Protection) for finding date of birth, DOB or D.O.B if there is something that looks like a date near those keywords before or after.  Ive found some expressions to look for a date and a keyword following but what if I want to search for DOB preceding or following a date?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi there, what have you tried? Is there any code to show us how you are trying to accomplish this? Here is a guideline of how you can improve the chances of getting an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: If I have the code below it should find some sort of date of birth statement followed by some sort of date?  What I’m trying to do is reduce any false positives for AIP to find a DOB with something that looks like a date (no need to verify)  when scanning

(?<=Date of birth:|DOB|D.O.B|Birth Date)\s* (?:\d{1,2}\s?[-\\/]?\s?\d{1,2}\s?[-\\/]?\s?\d{4} |(?:January|February|March| April|May|June|July|August|September| October|November|December),?\s?\d{1,2},?\s?\d{4})